# The UI isnt updated with a grouped observablecollection in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am relatively new to xamarin-forms and have been with this problem for days. I have read a lot of information and I can't solve it.
I have an observable collection that is grouped in the listview with the help of UpdateListContent (), I took this part from another website and it works fine. The problem is that when I modify the content and return to the screen where the groups are, the UI is not updated, the data arrives and is handled correctly, but not visible.
I read that you had to implement OnPropertyChanged to the OC so that the view is updated, I have tried it that way and in a thousand other ways, but I can't.
When I give OnPropertyChanged to the OC or when I try to force the view to be null and assign the data again, I always get the same error at:

> GroupedView.ItemsSource = "";
>
> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

With UpdateListContent () it's the only way I've found to do what I need, but I need the UI to update.
I'm probably doing something wrong, but my ideas are over and I can't find anything else.

**I really appreciate the help. Thank you.**

VS2019 16.2.4

XF 4.1.0

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class CandidatosView : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<CandidatoGroup> allGroups { get; set; }

    //private ObservableCollection<CandidatoGroup> _expandedGroups;

    //public ObservableCollection<CandidatoGroup> expandedGroups
    //{
    //    get { return _expandedGroups; }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        _expandedGroups = value;
    //        OnPropertyChanged("expandedGroups");
    //    }
    //}
    private ObservableCollection<CandidatoGroup> expandedGroups { get; set; }

    public CandidatosView()
    { }

    public CandidatosView(Guid IdOferta)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new CandidatosViewModel(IdOferta);
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        allGroups = CandidatosViewModel.All;
        allGroups.ForEach(x => x.Expanded = false);
        UpdateListContent();
    }
    private void HeaderTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        int selectedIndex = expandedGroups.IndexOf(
            ((CandidatoGroup)((Button)sender).CommandParameter));
        allGroups[selectedIndex].Expanded = !allGroups[selectedIndex].Expanded;
        UpdateListContent();
    }

    private void UpdateListContent()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<GestionCandidatoViewModel>(this, "Expanded", sender =>
        {
            allGroups.ForEach(x => x.Expanded = false);
        });
        expandedGroups = new ObservableCollection<CandidatoGroup>();
        foreach (CandidatoGroup group in allGroups)
        {
            CandidatoGroup newGroup = new CandidatoGroup(group.Title, group.ShortName, group.Expanded);
            newGroup.CandidatosCount = group.Count;
            if (group.Expanded)
            {
                foreach (Candidato candidato in group)
                {
                    newGroup.Add(candidato);
                }
            }
            expandedGroups.Add(newGroup);
        }
        try
        {
            GroupedView.ItemsSource = "";
            GroupedView.ItemsSource = expandedGroups;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

**CandidatoGroup class**

```
public class CandidatoGroup : ObservableCollection<Candidato>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _expanded;

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string TitleWithItemCount
        {
            get { return string.Format("{0} ({1})", Title, CandidatosCount); }
        }

        public string ShortName { get; set; }

        public bool Expanded
        {
            get { return _expanded; }
            set
            {
                if (_expanded != value)
                {
                    _expanded = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Expanded");
                    OnPropertyChanged("StateIcon");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string StateIcon
        {
            get { return Expanded ? "down" : "up"; }
        }

        public int CandidatosCount { get; set; }

        public CandidatoGroup(string title, string shortName, bool expanded = true)
        {
            Title = title;
            ShortName = shortName;
            Expanded = expanded;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not have to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you are using `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: hi there did you get anywhere with this? facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here

```
public CandidatosView(Guid IdOferta)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new CandidatosViewModel(IdOferta);
}
```

It should be `this` instead of `new CandidatosViewModel(IdOferta);`

**Corrected:**

```
public CandidatosView(Guid IdOferta)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

Comment: Hi. What do you rely on to believe that this is the solution?
I know that INotifyPropertyChanged with OC should not be necessary, but as I said before, I have read that OC needs it so that the view is updated, since without INPC, it does not update, I decided to try it and it happens that the same error occurs That when I try to refresh my view by force.
I do not understand this solution, it has absolutely nothing to do with the problem I have, my ViewModel needs that "IdOferta". Maybe I don't see it or I don't understand it, could you explain at least please. Thank you.

Comment: @ Danteou you can share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT  I'm sorry, but I'm using an API and a huge database, I couldn't share something so you can try it

Comment: You can use static data and test it.

Comment: facing the same issue. can't get messagingcenter updates to update a grouped listview. tried everything.